# Proxy error while installing Cypress on citrix machine

Tags: cypress, npm-install

I am trying to install cypress on my Citrix machine using command npm install --save-dev cypress (It was working fine earlier) but now getting this error-
[image]

also, the same is working fine on my Local, But there is no proxy connection I am using to access internet in my citrix machine, not sure why suddenly it is throwing proxy error, I am not able to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps mentioned in the below for reference -
Pre-Requisites (Node JS & Package.json Creation -

1. Download VS Code latest one
2. Download Node from Node.js site to install
3. Once installed add New System Variable under windows Environment Variables as "Variable name" as NODE_HOME and "Variable value as C:\Program Files\nodejs
4. Go to the Project Folder and open in Command Prompt as below -
5. Then run command npm init
6. Enter Name as below as highlighted in yellow as cypressautomation -
7. Press Enter till below -

   1. Then type yes Package.json file should get created
   2. Restart Visual Studio Code

---

Clean Install of Cypress from Scratch -   1. Clear Cypress by searching in windows and Shift Delete(Excluding the project folders)
2. Download Cypress from https://download.cypress.io/desktop/9.5.2 (Pass any version based from - https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog
3.Use this command in VS Code terminal as setx CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY rojectfolder.zip (Copy this zip file to any location and mention the path after CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY)
4. Restart Visual Studio Code d. Run from terminal - npm install cypress@10.3.0 (This will install node_modules & package. lock.json)
5. \node_modules.bin\cypress.cmd install -- force
6. add the below command under scripts in package.json -
Cypress :run": "set Cypress RUN BINARY.C://Users//%username%// AppData//Local//Cypress//Cache//9.5.2//Cypress//Cypress.exe&& cypress open --browser electron (set CYPRESS_RUN_BINARY=mention the Appdata Path for cypress.exe)

Answer (score 0):

We can figure out this issue using two steps.

step 1. Download cypress.zip file using URL that error has mentioned.

[image]

step 2 : run this command ***set CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=yourPath\cypress.zip && npm install cypress***